# Add external jar jwordpress-0.5.1.jar to android project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

I add an external jar jwordpress-0.5.1.jar.
In logcat I see:

- 12-30 09:34:41.041: E/dalvikvm(379): Could not find class 'net.bican.wordpress.Wordpress', referenced from method ru.androiden.client.MainActivity.onCreate
- 12-30 09:34:41.201: E/AndroidRuntime(379): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
- 12-30 09:34:41.201: E/AndroidRuntime(379): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.bican.wordpress.Wordpress

I have used several methods to add jar, for example:

- [how to add. JAR in my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564208/how-to-add-jar-in-my-project)
- [how to import external JSON jar file into ANDROID project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674601/how-to-import-external-json-jar-file-into-android-project)

What do I do? I have already solved this problem for two days.
Regards, Denis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **sounds** like the jar file is not being packaged with your application.

i.e. it's on your eclipse classpath (assuming eclipse's java editor didn't complain about your import statement?) so it's there at compile time. **BUT** the jar file isn't actually being bundled with your app, so the class that you're referencing isn't actually available at runtime.

To fix this, just create a libs directory in your project and follow the steps that you read to import the jar file from there. This should ensure that the jar gets bundled and its classes are available at runtime.

Comment: sorry, but I have a folder **libs** in my project. Do You say about this folder?

Comment: Ok, I'm not 100% sure what you've actually done... maybe have a squiz at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316445/how-to-use-and-package-a-jar-file-with-my-android-app

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that the jwordpress-0.5.1.jar built in Java 1.7, but the project built in Java 1.5.